# How to downgrade kernal version from 6.8 to 6.7 in Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Oracle Linux 6.7 is accidentally upgraded to 6.8 .  Need to downgrade it to 6.7.
**How do we edit menu.lst to change it to boot from Older Kernel?** without using yum downgrade
Here are some recent outputs,

```
[root@******cat /boot/grub/menu.lst
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_lkkddb02-lv_root
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Oracle Linux Server Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel (3.8.13-118.13.2.el6uek.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-3.8.13-118.13.2.el6uek.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_lkkddb02-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_root SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=256M rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_swap KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
initrd /initramfs-3.8.13-118.13.2.el6uek.x86_64.img
title Oracle Linux Server Red Hat Compatible Kernel (2.6.32-642.6.1.el6.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-642.6.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_lkkddb02-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_root SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=256M rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_swap KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-642.6.1.el6.x86_64.img
title Oracle Linux Server Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel (3.8.13-68.3.4.el6uek.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-3.8.13-68.3.4.el6uek.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_lkkddb02-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_root SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=256M rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_swap KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
initrd /initramfs-3.8.13-68.3.4.el6uek.x86_64.img
title Oracle Linux Server Red Hat Compatible Kernel (2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_lkkddb02-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_root SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_swap KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64.img

[root@*******~]# cat /proc/cmdline
ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_lkkddb02-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_root SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=256M rd_LVM_LV=vg_lkkddb02/lv_swap  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet

[root@******~]# uname -a
Linux lkkddb02.cclk.lk 3.8.13-118.13.2.el6uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Wed Oct 5 11:04:20 PDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@*******~]# cat /etc/oracle-release
Oracle Linux Server release 6.8

[root@*******~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)
```

Comment: Did you mean kernel version downgrade from 3.8 to 2.6? If yes, then that's easy. When the computer boots up, press an arrow key when grub shows - do this within 5 secs otherwise it will boot 3.8. Then go to extended options - whatever it shows, other than 'Oracle Linux Server Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel'. Then select 'Oracle Linux Server Red Hat Compatible Kernel' which will be 2.6 kernel. If this is what you're after, then post here and I'll add further instructions about how to always boot into that kernel.

Comment: No I wanted to boot from the 3.8.13-68.3.4.el6uek instead of 3.8.13-118.13.2.el6uek, But I have only access to this server by putty, no console. Therefore I have done this just changing to default=2 on menu.lst and reboot. However thank you for the support. And I was also able to down grade OS from 6.8 to 6.7 by using yum history undo ID as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this with following steps,

- Eble to boot from older kernel by just changing **default** value on menu.lst file
- Eble to down grade OS version older version by using the following steps

> ```
>  [root@test-db ~]# yum history
>     Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security, ulninfo
>     ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
>     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>      5 | root <root>              | 2016-10-17 21:29 | I, O, U        |  400 EE
>      4 | root <root>                | 2016-10-17 20:49 | I, O, U        |   58
>      3 | root <root>                | 2016-10-17 20:44 | D, E, I        |  458 EE
>      2 | root <root>                | 2016-10-17 17:10 | I, O, U        |  458 EE
>      1 | System <unset>           | 2016-10-17 11:54 | Install        | 1145
> history list
> ```
>
> `[root@test-db ~]# yum history undo 5`